# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi not available

Tags: wireless

My wifi adapter seems to have randomly dropped off with the last update. Has anyone else experienced this/know how it might be fixed?

Comment: The updates can stop the wifi adaptor drivers working. Sometimes it's best to just try and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix similar to the last time I has this issue:

[https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7~20.04.3_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu7%7E20.04.3_amd64.deb.html)

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

And my wifi is back up! Annoying that it keeps dropping off after updates though...

Comment: Your annoyance is understandable, and should properly be directed at the hardware manufacturer. They *could* create kernel modules that can update. They have *chosen* not to. Since their source code is non-free (restricted), there is nothing Ubuntu can do about it.